# Launch a ruby script from an HTML page?

Tags: ruby, html, watir

I'm running (on Windows) a Ruby script using Watir to automate some things for a specific website.

This script works but I wonder if it's possible to launch it directly from the browser?

In fact, what I want is to click on a favorites button (underline on the image of the link above) on my personnal bar and that it launch my script. (I don't know if it's really clear...)

[image: Screenshot]

To do this my first idea was to create a html file which launch my ruby script but I don't know at all how to launch a ruby script from a html (if it's possible)...

So if you have any idea, say it ;)

Comment: What you're asking for sounds like one of several possible security holes/exploits that were closed years ago.

Comment: @theTinMan : not really because I'm asking about launching a local script from a local html file. Not a local script from a website neither a distance script from a local html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you could run a local Rails app (server), which is then going to run any Ruby code in a controller — e.g. where you could invoke a commandline process like running a Ruby script.

Any browser bookmark is principally going to go to a webpage.  So you will need a webpage served locally, which then executes (local) server-side code that invokes your script.

Comment: It doesn't have to be Rails, which is extremely heavy for this. It just has to be a HTTPd and have the ability to launch a command-line script. It's easy to write using something like Sinatra or Ruby's built-in libraries.

Comment: @theTinMan that's fine and true.  I named rails only because I believed there would be more tutorials and related intro material.  There is probably some built-in IIS on their machine that they can use, I just have no clue.  Anything would work, as you said, that is a httpd server